# Android Workmanager vs Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin

There appears some confusion regarding the use of Android Workmanager and Kotlin Coroutines. What are the scenarios where they can be the best fit and when to use which?

Answer (score 3):

`WorkManager` is **android library** used to do stuffs in background asynchronously. It provides functionality to scheduled and repeated tasks in background.

So, it's best fit in your use case, when you've got some long running task to do. *(It's useful in latest versions of Android, API 26 and Up due to "Limits on background executions")*

---

`Coroutines` is **Kotlin library** as concept of new asynchronous programming, basically used to do stuffs off the main thread but waiting for response of new thread by suspension.

You can think of it as multi-threading programming aspect & In Android development, it can be alternative to `AsynTask` or `Handler`.

---

Hope, i made it clear about what to use when !

Comment: What "limits on background executions" are you referring to? In what way is it limited below API 26? The documentation says "WorkManager offers a backwards compatible (**API level 14+**) API..."

Comment: @user3738870 In that sentence, I referred to running background services in API 26 and above also known as "background execution limits". You simply can't run if your app is in background, you'll have to make your service foreground. In such case, workmanager is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now :) I think it's worth adding that the WorkManager API offers a good alternative to Services even below API 26.